# Count colored cells in multiple sheets in a single Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a master sheet in Google Spreadsheet as below;

[image]

what i want is to get color counts from a given tab/sheets(Column A) in google spreadsheet. According  to my research in stackoverflow, i found the code which works perfect in an active single sheet (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57571668/12906920);

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

  var backgrounds = activeSheet.getRange(countRange).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefBackground = activeSheet.getRange(colorRef).getBackground();

  var count = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<backgrounds.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<backgrounds[0].length;j++)
      if( backgrounds[i][j] == colorRefBackground )
        count=count+1;
  return count;
};
```

But i could not add sheet name (cell value) as argument . For example; to get given sheet2 color in a given range with reference to B1, my function could  be:

```
countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef,sheet_name) > countColoredCells(F1:F30,B1,A2)
```

the function looks which sheets' range will be searched and return the count values from reference color in master excel. Can someone help me how to do that?

**UPDATE**

Here the modified code but i still get "range not found error"

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef,sheetName) {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName));
    var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
    var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

    var backgrounds = activeSheet.getRange(countRange).getBackgrounds();
    var colorRefBackground = activeSheet.getRange(colorRef).getBackground();

    var count = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<backgrounds.length;i++)
      for(var j=0;j<backgrounds[0].length;j++)
        if( backgrounds[i][j] == colorRefBackground )
        count=count+1;
    return count;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying the function to add a sheet name argument and `.getSheetByName()` method?

Comment: IMHO you will have more chances to get help if you show what you tried to adapt the code to your specific needs.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I think Google Sheets does not support VBA .Sheets supports Javascript functions working just as macros

Comment: @TheMaster .getSheetByName is fine but i have more than 30 tabs/sheet and everytime i need to add string manually into that. It requires parameter as string but i could not pass the selected cell as string argument into that sheet name.

Comment: You could pass. See how `countRange` is passed. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources on basics of JavaScript. It'll barely take 5 hours to do a full course and 5-15 minutes to get what you're looking for. If you don't still get it, [edit] your question with what you've tried.

Comment: There's also `.getSheets()` method on class Spreadsheet

Comment: @TheMaster, i changed the code but i still get range not found error.

Comment: On which line?``.``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original function, just change `var backgrounds = activeSheet.getRange(countRange).getBackgrounds();`
to

```
  const backgrounds = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getRange(countRange)
    .getBackgrounds();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Background Color Count in a column

Defaults to active spreadsheet, active sheet and column 1

```
function getBGColorCount(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || 1;
  const bgs = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getMaxRows()).getBackgrounds().flat();
  let colors = { pA: [] };
  bgs.forEach((c, i) => {
    if (!colors.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
      colors[c] = 1;
      colors.pA.push(c);
    } else {
      colors[c] += 1;
    }
  });
  let html = '<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;width:25px;}</style><table>';
  //add this to remove white filter(p => p != "#ffffff")
  colors.pA.forEach(p => {
    html += `<tr><td style="background-color:${p};"></td><td>${colors[p]}</td></tr>`;
  });
  html += '</table>'
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Color Count');
}
```

[image]

#### Multiple Sheets

```
function getBGColorCountMultipleSheets(col, shts, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts = shts || ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet0'];
  var col = col || 1;
  let colors = { pA: [] };
  ss.getSheets().filter(s => ~shts.indexOf(s.getName())).forEach(sh => {
    let bgs = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getMaxRows()).getBackgrounds().flat();
    bgs.forEach((c, i) => {
      if (!colors.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
        colors[c] = 1;
        colors.pA.push(c);
      } else {
        colors[c] += 1;
      }
    });
  });
  let html = '<style>td,th{border:1px solid black;width:25px;}</style><table>';
  //add this to remove white filter(p => p != "#ffffff")
  colors.pA.forEach(p => {
    html += `<tr><td style="background-color:${p};"></td><td>${colors[p]}</td></tr>`;
  });
  html += '</table>'
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Color Count');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for counting colored cells in multiple sheets in a single google spreadsheet:

```
function goToSheet(countRange,colorRef,sheetName) {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName));
    var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
    var formula = activeRange.getFormula();

    const backgrounds = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      .getSheetByName(sheetName)
      .getRange(countRange)
      .getBackgrounds();
    var colorRefBackground = activeSheet.getRange(colorRef).getBackgrounds();

    var count = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<backgrounds.length;i++)
      for(var j=0;j<backgrounds[0].length;j++)
        if( backgrounds[i][j] == colorRefBackground )
        count=count+1;
    return count;

}
```

I would like to thank user
https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster who helped me to achieve it and also, i changed

```
var colorRefBackground = activeSheet.getRange(colorRef).getBackground()
```

to

```
var colorRefBackground = activeSheet.getRange(colorRef).getBackgrounds()
```

which returns the background colors of the cells in the range.

Comment: Are you saying it didn't work if you didn't change `var colorRefBackground = activeSheet.getRange(colorRef).getBackground()`?

Comment: it always returned "1". @TheMaster

Comment: That's strange. Could you quote the formula you used?

Comment: =goToSheet("F1:F30","B1",A3).@TheMaster

Comment: This returned the name of the cell written in mastersheet > "A3" cell ,and it looked the sheet written in A3 and returned the count of referenced "B1" color in A3 sheet and wrote the result in master excel. @TheMaster

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that line shouldn't make any difference whatsoever. Maybe other scripts in your project or copy of this function is interfering. Anyway, if it works, no problem.

Comment: Thank you so much.